# Is it possible when we define an object to set an attribute with the value of another attribute of itself?

Tags: javascript, object

I would like when I'm creating an object in Js to be able to define an attribut including the value of a previous attribut of the same object (therefore not to repeat element if I want to define an attribut with a part of an other attribut), but I don't know if it's possible.
I show you my code:

```
var Sel = {
    timSand: document.getElementById('tim-sand'),
    timSandHei: getComputedStyle(timSand).height, // not Working
}


var Sel = {
    timSand: document.getElementById('tim-sand'),
    timSandHei: getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('tim-sand')).height, // Working but a bit dirty
}
```

So when I'm doing the first exemple, I have an error, and I have to replace `timSand` in the second line by `document.getElementById('tim-sand')`, like on the second exemple.
Do you know a way to avoid this ?

Comment: It is not possible to reference part of an object inside its object initializer expression.

Comment: You could define a variable and use that within the object. That would be nicer imo eg. `var timSandElement = document.getElementById('tim-sand')` - `timSand: timSandElement ` & `timSandHei: getComputedStyle(timSandElement).height`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot because the object does not exist yet, so you cannot reference it.

But you can use a variable to avoid the heavy DOM access.

```js
var sand = document.getElementById('tim-sand')
var Sel = {
  timSand: sand,
  timSandHei: getComputedStyle(sand).height, //Working 
}
```